# How to setup an emergency access accounts in Azure AD using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have configured the emergency access accounts in Azure AD following the article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/security-emergency-access however I want this to be configured using the Terraform script.

How to setup an emergency access accounts in Azure AD using Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need a create a App Registration, add the "Owner" role assignment for the App Registration. Use tenant_id, client_id, client_secret in the provider block.

Follow the link to create a App Registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

Provide Required Api Permissions to the App Reg. Once you Create the App Registration and client secret(Store in a Key Vault Secret as it will be shown only one time). Open Subscription>Access control (IAM)>Add Role assignments>Owner> Select members(select your app registration)> Next>finish.

API Permissions Screenshot :
[App Registration API Permissions][1]

It's fine if you have already created a App Registration. App Registration must have owner role assignments and domain, directory role assignment read write permissions.

Use the below code you can able to create a User and Assign a role to the user.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {

  #Configuration options 
  tenant_id     = "tenant id of your"     
  client_id     = "use client ID of your"     
  client_secret = "use client Secret of your" 
}

resource "azuread_user" "aduser" {
  user_principal_name = "azure.terraform@gmohankumar0341hotmail.onmicrosoft.com"
  display_name        = "azterraform"
  mail_nickname       = "aztf"
  password            = "Terraform@123"
  country             = "India"
}

resource "azuread_directory_role" "ad-role" {
  display_name = "Global administrator"
  depends_on = [
    azuread_user.aduser
  ]
}

resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "aduser" {
  role_id             = azuread_directory_role.ad-role.template_id
  principal_object_id = azuread_user.aduser.object_id
  depends_on = [
    azuread_user.aduser
  ]
}

[terraform apply command Screenshot][2]
[User created Reference Screenshot][3]
[Assigned roles Screenshot][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBr7y.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zhP3.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tlCe.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MScgE.png
```